# 2D Hexagon grid

Tags: lua, grid-layout

I recently made a simple lua class (this is using the love2D engine) that made a hexagon by plotting 6 vertices and tracing them with lines, one of the things I wanted to be able to expand to was a hexagon grid but I didn't know how

All of the websites I found didn't help and I couldn't understand why.

Here's the function where I plot the vertices based on it's radius and x and y position.

My hexagons are in a pointy-topped style.

```
function hexagon.new(x,y,radius)
    local hexagon=setmetatable({},hexagon)
    hexagon.Vertices={}
    hexagon.x=x or 0
    hexagon.radius = radius or 10 
    hexagon.y=y or 0
    for i=0,6 do
        local angle = 2 * math.pi / 6 * (i + .5) -- 1 is what is multipled to 90(2*math.pi) so 1*90=90(flat-topped), 0.5*90=45(pointy-topped)
        local x = hexagon.x + hexagon.radius * math.cos(angle)
        local y = hexagon.y + hexagon.radius * math.sin(angle)
        hexagon.Vertices[i]= {x=x,y=y}
    end
    return hexagon
end
```

Comment: You might find [this article](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons) useful

Comment: I've tried that but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i understood well.
Here is working example of how to create hex and then draw it to grid with as simplified functions as possible, using Love2d engine (v. 0.10.2).

important: made for hex which has all six points on circle, using radius.
this approach is not suitable for all hex shapes.

```
------------------------------
--lets create hex data with center at position 0,0
--using only simple functions

--table of 6 points
hex = {};
--radius for hex which has all 6 points lying on circle
hex.radius = 10;

--simple loop to generate hex
local i = 1
repeat

    --full circle has 2 radians and hex has 6 points
    --so 1/3 pi increase per point
    local direction = math.pi/3 * (i+0.5)
    --rotate hex by 90 degrees: direction = math.pi/3 * i

    --generate empty table to insert point coordinations to
    hex[i] = {};
    --set x,y coordinates
    hex[i].x = hex.radius*math.cos( direction )
    hex[i].y = hex.radius*math.sin( direction )
    i = i+1

until i > 6
------------------------------

------------------------------
function love.draw( dt )

    --get distance between 2 hex tiles using trigonometry
    local jxOffset = hex.radius*-math.tan( math.pi/1.5 ) --or math.sqrt(3) * hex.radius
    --offset new lines by this value
    local ixOffset = jxOffset/4
    --use direction and distance to get "y" offset between lines
    --we got distance in jxOffset, so we just apply direction 
    local iyOffset = jxOffset*math.sin( math.pi/3 )

    --"i" = line, "j" = tile in line
    local i = 1
    repeat
        local j = 1
        repeat

            love.graphics.push()
            --offset drawable position (or draw hex tile at position):
            love.graphics.translate( ixOffset+j*jxOffset, i*iyOffset )
            --draw poly-line between all hex points - creating hex
            love.graphics.line( hex[1].x,hex[1].y, hex[2].x,hex[2].y, hex[3].x,hex[3].y, hex[4].x,hex[4].y, hex[5].x,hex[5].y, hex[6].x,hex[6].y, hex[1].x,hex[1].y );
            love.graphics.pop()
            j = j+1

        until j > 5

        --invert for each new line
        --keep lines from increasing x coordinates
        ixOffset = -ixOffset
        i = i+1

    until i > 5

end
------------------------------
```

Excuse me if i made mistake somewhere, ran the code and worked properly on my side. If you discover anything off, comment and i will try to fix it.

[image: hopefully explains what i did with the offsets]